Formatting XML tags in a column
I have a script that will line up my XML in rows based on my <LD> tag.
<LD><ML><NUM>1234</NUM>
<LD><ML><NUM>2345</NUM>
<LD><SL><NUM>3456</NUM></SL></LD>
<LD><ED>SOMEDATA</ED><NUM>4567</NUM></LD>
I would like to have the <NUM> be lined up in a columnar fashion like below:
<LD><ML>                                 <NUM>1234</NUM>
<LD><ML>                                 <NUM>2345</NUM>
<LD><SL>                                   <NUM>3456</NUM></SL></LD>
<LD><ED>SOMEDATA</ED>     <NUM>4567</NUM></LD>
Any ideas on how to format an XML tag into a column?
I have tried to add tab keys in but I am not sure how to count how many each row needs.
